# remove print button

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I'm creating charts with the HighCharts library and I wonder how to remove the 2 little buttons on the right corner which one you can print and download graphs and I'd like to add a new one.

Maybe someone could help me?

Answer (score 6):

You can disable the buttons if you like, according to [the documentation](http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#exporting-buttons-printButton--enabled). The documentation even provides [an example](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/navigation/buttonoptions-enabled/) of the chart being loaded, with the buttons disabled.

In  your configuration, be sure to include the following:

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    /* Other items removed to focus on navigation */
    navigation: {
        buttonOptions: {
            enabled: false
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to remove all buttons the best place to do it is here:

```
exporting: {
    enabled: false
}
```

If you disable on the navigation only buttons are disabled, the exporting module continue to be loaded.
To disable only one button you have to use the following:

```
exporting: {
    buttons: {
        exportButton: {
            enabled: false
        }
    }
}
```

The code below disable the export button.
I don't know how to add a button without adding a new svg element, but if you won't to use export buttons, why don't you change your chart button style and function ? You can do it following the **[reference](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/ref/#exporting-buttons-printButton)**.

Answer (score 1):

As explained above, you can disable by,

```
exporting: {
    buttons: {
        exportButton: {
            enabled: false
        }
    }
}
```

To add a new button use this,

[Add a new image button in highcharts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9218490/highcharts-add-a-custom-image-button)