# Remove Export and print button plugin on highchart chart

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, charts, highcharts

I am using MVC and currently working with highchart

I am using the Exporting.js so users can print or export the highchart chart.
I have two charts in a view and I would like to disable print and export on one of the chart. How can I do that?

Exporting.js is automaticly giving charts  these 2 button options.

Thanks in dvance

Correct solution:

```
.SetExporting(new Exporting { Enabled = false, EnableImages = false });
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See the following ['Exporting module is loaded but disabled'](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/exporting/enabled-false/) for how to disable exporting.  An explanation of all of the modifiable options for exporting can be found [here](http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#exporting--enabled).

**EDIT**

It looks like you are using DotNet.Highcharts.  Here is an example on how to use and set the exporting features:

```
.SetExporting(new Exporting
{
    Buttons = new ExportingButtons
        {
            ExportButton = new ExportingButtonsExportButton
                {
                    Align = HorizontalAligns.Right,
                        //BackgroundColor  <-- Don't know how to set yet
                        BorderColor = Color.Black,
                        BorderRadius = 3,
                        BorderWidth = 1,
                        Enabled = true,
                        Height = 35,
                        HoverBorderColor = Color.Red,
                        HoverSymbolFill = Color.Black,
                        HoverSymbolStroke = Color.Black,
                        //Onclick
                        //MenuItems
                        SymbolSize = 25,
                        SymbolX = 18,
                        SymbolY = 18,
                        VerticalAlign = VerticalAligns.Top,
                        Width = 35,
                        Y = 10,
                        X = -50
                },
                PrintButton = new ExportingButtonsPrintButton
                {
                    Align = HorizontalAligns.Right,
                        //BackgroundColor  <-- Don't know how to set yet
                        BorderColor = Color.Black,
                        BorderRadius = 3,
                        BorderWidth = 1,
                        Enabled = true,
                        Height = 35,
                        HoverBorderColor = Color.Red,
                        HoverSymbolFill = Color.Black,
                        HoverSymbolStroke = Color.Black,
                        //Onclick
                        //MenuItems
                        SymbolStroke = Color.Teal,
                        SymbolSize = 25,
                        SymbolX = 18,
                        SymbolY = 18,
                        VerticalAlign = VerticalAligns.Top,
                        Width = 35,
                        Y = 10,
                        X = -15
                }
    },
        Enabled = true,
        EnableImages = true,
        Filename = "HomeChart",
        Type = "image/png",
        Url = "http://export.highcharts.com",
        Width = 800
})
```

Comment: Does not work for newer version of DotNetHighcharts... No option for 'PrintButton'  in ExportingButtonsExportButton  the only available option is ContextButton which can be disabled removing all of the options. How can I do this for just print? Thanks

Comment: I am using HighCharts version 3.0.2. Have set up the Highcharts server locally for exporting the charts. When download as png/jpeg/pdf is selected from the top right corner of the chart , the Highcharts demo page is displayed. so how can stop that redirection can please help me

Answer (score 72):

You can disable both the buttons (i.e. the whole exporting section) simulataneously by,

```
exporting: {
         enabled: false
}
```

You can also disable any one or both of them like this,

```
exporting: {
    buttons: { 
        exportButton: {
            enabled:false
        },
        printButton: {
            enabled:false
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: exporting: false is also perfectly acceptable if your intent is to disable completely.

Comment: can anyone provide a working fiddle with specific exporting options? i was able to disable all of them, but not to pick specific export options.
for example, i would like to allow printing only, but not to export as SVG

Comment: @LiranBrimer, set  `enable: false` for every button except `print` button.

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle of your attempt ?

Comment: I am using HighCharts version 3.0.2. Have set up the Highcharts server locally for exporting the charts. When download as png/jpeg/pdf is selected from the top right corner of the chart , the Highcharts demo page is displayed. so how can stop that redirection can please help me

Answer (score 5):

The first option that you mention:

```
exporting: {
         enabled: false
}
```

breaks the highcharts object, if you are using it in a scenario in which you reuse the html container (ie refreshing data).

the only viable option for me in that scenario is combining both:

```
  optionsMini.exporting = {
        enabled: false,
        buttons: {
            exportButton: {
                enabled: false
            },
            printButton: {
                enabled: false
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The below works for the MVC 5 and Highsoft.Highcharts 
I added it before this line: `Title = new Title { Text = "charts" },`

```
Exporting = new Exporting { Enabled = false },
```